# Unable to add wlan1 interface

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

I am trying to make a WiFi router from NanoPi M1+ device. It will have two working modes that is Eth<-->WiFi and WiFi<-->WiFi.

I am able to execute the first mode perfectly, but the second mode where the device has to work as a station and Access Point is troubling me.

The NanoPi device has a built-in WiFi chipset and I am using an addition WiFi adapter for another mode.

The issue is, the device is unable to show the second WLAN interface. On manually adding an interface using iw it throws an error.

I have included the output of the commands in the following.

```
ifconfig:
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:81:c7:86:31:ec
          inet addr:192.168.55.227  Bcast:192.168.55.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7f3c:fbbd:4f8a:34b4/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fc00::74dd:b4f:9f39:8b36/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fc00::c1ed:d2fc:ae81:f2c0/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4987 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2008 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3871199 (3.8 MB)  TX bytes:160738 (160.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:614 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:614 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:64279 (64.2 KB)  TX bytes:64279 (64.2 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b0:f1:ec:2c:ea:c6
          inet6 addr: fe80::b2f1:ecff:fe2c:eac6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:542 (542.0 B)  TX bytes:1130 (1.1 KB)
```

The wlan0 interface should work for Access Point mode and wlan1 interface as a station.

```
/etc/network/interfaces:
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static  
address 172.24.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 172.24.1.0
broadcast 172.24.1.255

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp
```

hostapd file:

```
driver=nl80211
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
beacon_int=100
auth_algs=1
#wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
ssid=test02c00081c78631ec
channel=7
hw_mode=g
#wpa_passphrase=raspberry
interface=wlan0
#wpa=2
#wpa_pairwise=TKIP
country_code=IN
```

dnsmasq.conf file:

```
domain-needed
interface=wlan0
except-interface=lo
dhcp-range=192.168.41.10,192.168.41.150,255.255.255.0,12h
#address=/#/192.168.41.1
#server=/192.168.0.245/8.8.8.8
log-dhcp
log-queries
log-facility=/tmp/dnsmasq.log
```

On **lsusb**, it shows the network adapter,  Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter

```
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 020: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp.
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

On doing :

```
iw dev wlan0 interface add wlan1 type station flags none
```

throws an error:

```
command failed: Operation not supported (-95)
```

I added wlan1 as an interface in **/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules** file, but still wlan1 can't be recognised.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="C0-25-E9-25-AB-14", NAME=="wlan1"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="b0:f1:ec:2c:ea:c6", NAME=="wlan0"
```

Please tell what I am missing and how can I add wlan1 as an interface?

Comment: I'm not an expert on Linux kernels and drivers but I suspect you don't have a driver installed for that Realtek chipset.

Comment: Like above. In Debian or Raspbian it's the `firmware-realtek` package, I think. What OS does your NanoPi run?

Comment: Can you post the output of `iw phy`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski its friendlycore-xenial_4.14

Comment: @grawity its strange no output of iw **phy**  neither for iw list

Comment: Also, IIRC the RTL8188 has driver issues, so even if you *have* drivers, it may need some fiddling to get it working. Like getting the right firmware. Look at `dmesg` to find out what the kernel is doing wrt. drivers when you attach the USB WLAN stick.